# How did Smurfette know her origins in "The Smurfs" (2011) and then, suddenly, she learns Gargamel is her creator in "The Smurfs 2" (2013)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-smurfs, the-smurfs-2

I'm going to focus on the following question: **how did Smurfette know her origins in [*The Smurfs* (2011)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs_(film)) and then, suddenly, she learns Gargamel is her creator in [*The Smurfs 2*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Smurfs_2)?**

Unfortunately, most of the movie clips aren't available in Croatia, which makes things more difficult since both of the movies are relatively old, but I'm going to recall the intimate conversation between Grace Winslow and Smurfette in *The Smurfs* (2011) when *Smurfette* revealed Grace it was Gargamel who created her in the first place:

> Grace Winslow: How can you be the girl in the village?
>
> Smurfette: Well see, I wasn't brought by a stork-like the others. **I was created by Gargamel** to trap the other Smurfs.
>
> Grace Winslow: Wow! And then what happened?
>
> Smurfette: Papa saved me. He cast a special spell and then helped become the Smurf I was meant to be.
>
> [source](https://www.quotes.net/mquote/1197542)

On the other hand, the plot motivation of the movie sequel from 2013 is Smurfette not knowing where she really originates.

> *The Smurfs 2* is the 2013 sequel to the previous Smurf movie. In this sequel, **Smurfette finds out that she was created by Gargamel** and only later adopted by Papa Smurf. When adopting her, Papa Smurf infused her with a magic potion, which turned her, from her previous grey appearance, into the blue Smurf she now is. Apparently Smurfette also had a choice whether or not she wanted to be a blue Smurf and remain with them in the Smurf village. **Though her past is long forgotten, on her birthday, Smurfette remembers her "roots'** and, feeling a little ignored and neglected, she goes for a walk in the forest.
>
> [source](http://worm-to-butterfly.blogspot.com/2013/)

This still seems contrary to me even after 7 years. I must admit I didn't enjoy the 2013 sequel as much as I'd thought I would. I thought something was wrong with me because nobody around me in the cinema seemed to bother. When Smurfette spoke to Grace in the 2011 movie, she remembered where she'd come from, but, according to the 2013 sequel, she remembers her origin only on her birthday(s). She didn't celebrate her birthday at the time she first came to New York, did she?